# How to get CPU usage of Envoy (istio-proxy) container from another container in the POD

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, istio, envoyproxy

POD consist: `my-app-container` and `envoy (istio-proxy)` container

I want to get `cpu_usage` of `envoy-container` from `may-app-container`.

Info from: `http://localhost:1500/stats` and `http://localhost:1500/stats/prometheus` doesn't contain `CPU_usage`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are 2 ways I could find to get the information about istio-proxy cpu usage.

---

You can use [kubectl top](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#top).

```
kubectl top pods -A --containers | grep istio-proxy | grep Mi
default        details-v1-66b6955995-g98g6                                 istio-proxy                 3m           42Mi
default        productpage-v1-5d9b4c9849-v4pwv                             istio-proxy                 3m           40Mi
default        ratings-v1-fd78f799f-qcpwn                                  istio-proxy                 3m           38Mi
default        reviews-v1-6549ddccc5-hg4sw                                 istio-proxy                 4m           64Mi
default        reviews-v2-76c4865449-kzknx                                 istio-proxy                 4m           55Mi
default        reviews-v3-6b554c875-7txzl                                  istio-proxy                 3m           53Mi
istio-system   istio-ingressgateway-5656d66f9f-2f25t                       istio-proxy                 3m           36Mi
```

---

You can also follow the Istio [Wiki](https://github.com/istio/istio/wiki/Analyzing-Istio-Performance) to analyze Istio performance, including the [cpu](https://github.com/istio/istio/wiki/Analyzing-Istio-Performance#cpu).

Comment: hmmm it's helpfull :)I'll think about it. Maybe you known how can I get CPU utilization without connection to K8S API or etc. Only from my-application-container in the same POD.

Comment: @srg321 Unfortunately I don't know how to do that from your application container in the same pod.